# Making Android App invisible in Google Play and only accessible via Url

Tags: android, google-play

I developed a new Android App and I would like to test the app among my inner friend circle.  Therefore I want to publish the app to Google Play, but the app should not be visible to normal users, when they search for related keywords.

Only if I send the exact link to a user to, like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mydomain.myapp, I want them to see it and download it.

Is it possible to hide your App from search results?

BTW: I know this is not totally programming related, but who else would know, if not developers.

Answer (score 1):

The "APK" section of the Google Play Developer Console has a "Beta Testing" tab that you can use to make versions available only to certain users.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en